# How to securely access local data in remote SLURM job w/o exposing sensitive information?

Tags: bash, security, ssh, file-transfer, slurm

I want to run a SLURM job on a remote cluster to analyze sensitive data stored locally (`/data/mydata.csv`). The job is defined in `job.sh`, which executes an analysis script (`r_script.R`) for data analysis. To avoid uploading sensitive data to the remote server, I attempted to directly load it from the local system pasting an SSH command together within `r_script.R`,

```
ssh user@local.ip 'cat /data/mydata.csv'
```

which essentially opens a connection to load the data into memory.

I set up SSH key pairs for passwordless access and wrote a Bash script (`job.sh`) with a `-d` flag for specifying the data file location.

This setup **works fine when running the script directly**,

```
$ ./job.sh -d user@local.ip:/data/mydata.csv
```

but **fails under SLURM**,

```
$ sbatch ./job.sh -d user@local.ip:/data/mydata.csv
```

due to unavailable SSH or SSH keys in SLURM, resulting in a `status 255` error. Tried `ssh-add -L` which indeed fails.

Considering an alternative to `wget` a password-protected `.zip` and pass the password with a `-p` flag for interactive input, I realized this exposes the password in plain text, which is not secure.

I am looking for a method, such as an `sbatch` flag or a secure file transfer protocol available in SLURM, to securely transfer my sensitive local data to a SLURM job while avoiding direct uploads. How can this be achieved?

I can share scripts for more context if needed. Any insights or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Nobody can access your data except the admins. If you don't trust the admins, then probably use your personal computer. You can opt for online solutions such as Google drive but depends on how the node is configured. If the compute node doesn't allow internet access then you have to upload a part of the data or the entire data on the cluster, no matter what technique you use.